# What is "from" here? how translate "America's second biggest wrestling federation"?

Tags: grammar, grammar-myths

What is "from" here?

> America's second biggest wrestling federation finally hit consoles with a roster of 25 stars to choose **from**.

Answer (score 3):

"America's second biggest wrestling federation finally hit consoles with a roster of 25 stars to choose from."

"What is 'from' here?"

**"From"** is a preposition. The statement can be re-worded to read as follows:

> "The second-largest wrestling federation in the United States is finally available to watch with a roster of 25 stars (i.e. well-known professional wrestlers) ***from which*** to choose."

For more information about the ***subject*** of wrestling federations in America, please refer to this Wikipedia article on the [**History of professional wrestling in the United States.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_professional_wrestling_in_the_United_States) While the [**WWE ("World Wrestling Entertainment")**](http://www.wwe.com) currently dominates wrestling sports-entertainment on television in the United States, there were (and still are) many other *regional* American wrestling federations, some of which you can read about here: [**"Before WWE: 25 Very Best Wrestling Territories."**](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1036248-the-20-very-best-wrestling-territories) The WWE (formerly called the **WWF, "World Wrestling Federation"**) is the "biggest wrestling federation" in America, but I was not able to determine who is the "second biggest." The inclusion of the links in this paragraph is to help with understanding and translating the question.

Comment: how translate “America's second biggest wrestling federation”?

Comment: Please see the paragraph I added, above. I hope the additional information is helpful to you.